# Swing Mouse Click Event for JMenu and JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, menu, mouseevent, contextmenu

I would like to have Eclipse behavior for mouse clicks outside menus and popup menus in Swing. Basically, in Eclipse, when you press the mouse OUTSIDE the menu, the menu disappears and the mouse press event is forwarded to the component on which you clicked with the mouse.

Irritatingly, Swing does not do this, and I can't find a way around it.

Right now, even with Windows LAF, i have to click a second time to get the component to register the mouse click.

For the sake of the response just do it on a table

```
final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
JMenuItem viewProfile = new JMenuItem("View Profile");
viewProfile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   }
});
popupMenu.add(viewProfile);
table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
```

EDIT: here is a test code. I don't think it is convenient to add a mouse listener to every simple component so they can register mouse clicks after a popup menu. In the following example, the Table does implement it, but not the Button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestMouse {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new TestMouse();
   }

   private JLabel  counter;

   private int     count;

   private JPanel  northPanel;

   private JButton clickMe;

   public TestMouse() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B" }, 10);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);

            northPanel = new JPanel();

            clickMe = new JButton("Button");
            clickMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  System.out.println("clicked");
                  count++;
               }
            });
            counter = new JLabel("0");

            northPanel.add(counter);
            northPanel.add(clickMe);

            final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem viewProfile = new JMenuItem("View Profile");
            viewProfile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               }
            });
            popupMenu.add(viewProfile);
            table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

               @Override
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                  System.out.println("clicked");
                  count++;
                  counter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
               }

            });

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't seem to be able to replicate the issue.

When I right click the table, the popup menu appears and when I click the table again (to dismiss the popup), the `mouseClicked` event is triggered.

[image: ClicktyClack]

Note the counter in the north position...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestMouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMouse();
    }

    private JLabel counter;
    private int count;

    public TestMouse() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                        new Object[]{"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"},
                        10
                );
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                counter = new JLabel("0");

                final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                JMenuItem viewProfile = new JMenuItem("View Profile");
                viewProfile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.add(viewProfile);
                table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
                table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("clicked");
                        count++;
                        counter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    }

                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(counter, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

A actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: good start of an answer. but i would like something at the level of the system or the popup system. I don't think making mouse listeners on every components is a good design idea. You don't need a mouse listener for the JButton regular mouse events. why should we need one for those popup hiding mouse events?

Comment: Popups are automatically when they lose focus. Buttons gave there own mouse listeners which trigger an action listener. What is it you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem when closing JMenuBar popups, and this worked for me:

```
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.consumeEventOnClose", false);
```

Comment: Oh my, what an information gold nugget! This behaviour has been driving me crazy on more than one occasion over the past years.